# Custom date picker throws exception windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, custom-datetimepicker

I am developing a windows phone application. In that I wanted a functionality such that if a text box gets focus date picker should be opened. Similarly another text box will trigger a time picker.

i searched and found that this can be achieved with writing a custom date/time picker. I successfully got the time picker working in this fashion but when I tried to implement the same method for date picker I'm getting the following exception.

```
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
```

The XAML code for the time and date picker are as follows.

```
<popUps:CustomTimePicker x:Name="timePicker" Visibility="Collapsed" Value="{Binding SelectedTime, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<popUps:CustomDatePicker x:Name="datePicker" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

The custom date picker class which I wrote for the same is

```
class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public void ClickDateTemplateButton()
    {
        ApplyTemplate();

        Button button = (GetTemplateChild("DateTimeButton") as Button);
        if (button != null)
        {

            ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
            if (peer != null)
            {
                IInvokeProvider provider = (peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider);
                if (provider != null)
                {
                    provider.Invoke();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Please help me finding where it went wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a derived class and explicitly launching the derived datePicker after a textBox gets focus, when thats the default behavior of the DatePicker and you could use it straight away?

Comment: What happens if you remove the Visibility attribute from your CustomDatePicker?

Comment: Actually my need is to show "Date"( a string value ) initially when displaying the datepicker. Then after the user selects the date the date should be visible. This is not possible with the default datepicker, if I'm right. That's why I tried doing this.

Comment: Same exception is being thrown when the visibility is set to "Visible"

Comment: Have you added the datepicker in your page's layout? Or are you referencing it from a resource?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adding the datepicker in page's layout.

Comment: I added the "Windows Phone toolkit" package, then directly included the namespace.

Comment: No, I mean if it is added in your page's layoutGrid `Grid` or if your referencing it as a resource in your page. I'm doing the exact same thing in an app and I remember dealing with the same exception at some point but I can't remember how I've solved it. Currently I'm using the datePicker in the code behind. I'm posting an answer with my usage.

Comment: Actually this is under a data template of a listbox. So each list item will have one datepicker and timepicker and few more controls. SO I think adding in code behind wont solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, don't add the customDatePicker in your listBoxItem DataTemplate.
Whenever you want to launch the controls, call the following method. You will need to save the index of your selected listBoxItem in your page's transient State in order to populate the correct Item of your listbox with the selected value, after you return to your page, when the datepicker page closes.

```
private void LanchDatePicker()
{
    datepicker = new CustomDatePicker
    {
        IsTabStop = false, 
        MaxHeight = 0,
        Value = null
    };

   datepicker.ValueChanged += DatePicker_OnValueChanged;
   LayoutRoot.Children.Add(datepicker);
   datepicker.ClickTemplateButton();
}
```

Comment: It opens the datePicker. Will have to check with the other difficulties like binding the values and all that. Thanks although.

Comment: Save the selected ListBoxitem's `DataContext`, which is an instance of your custom class you use for your binding. When you return to your page after selecting a value in the `DatePicker`, populate that item in your binding source with the choosen values.